# r - 'rbind' dataframes with different prefix in column names

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, rbind

I have two dataframes like the following:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1:4),
       Year = 2001,
       a_Var1 = c("A","B","C","D"),
       a_Var2 = c("T","F","F","T"))

df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1:4),
       Year = 2002,
       b_Var1 = c("E","F","G","H"))
```

The desired end product is

```
df_combined <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4),
                      Year = c(2001,2002,2001,2002,2001,2002,2001,2002),
                      Var1 = c("A","E","B","F","C","G","D","H"),
                      Var2 = c("T",NA,"F",NA,"F",NA,"T",NA))
```

Question is how to 'rbind' in such a way that the prefix `a_` or `b_` is removed and `Var1`, `Var2`, etc become the new columns.

Tried `plyr`'s `rbind.fill` but that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Do you want to just remove the `a_`, `b_`, etc from column names before binding? `dplyr::rename_all` or `purrr::set_names` with regex is handy

Comment: Thank you. I'll prefer not to & just combine the dfs but will remember this approach for future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option.  Place the datasets in a `list`, `rename` by removing the prefix part including the `_` and `arrange` by 'ID'

```
library(tidyverse)
map_df(list(df1, df2), ~ .x %>% 
             rename_all(~ str_remove(.x, "^[^_]+_"))) %>%
   arrange(ID)
#  ID Year Var1 Var2
#1  1 2001    A    T
#2  1 2002    E <NA>
#3  2 2001    B    F
#4  2 2002    F <NA>
#5  3 2001    C    F
#6  3 2002    G <NA>
#7  4 2001    D    T
#8  4 2002    H <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks akrun! Could you please make a slight modification to your answer - could you make it such that the code takes into account all variables in all dataframes (i.e. one doesn't need to specify "Var1", "Var2", etc individually)?

Comment: @JunranCao  I changed it

Comment: Thank you very much! I will accept your answer as soon as the time restriction is up.